# How do I replace my shower diverter lever?

Tags: plumbing-fixture

My wife went to change over the shower from bathtub to shower and the lever popped right out. I’m not familiar with this style - there’s no screws underneath and I tried manually turning the spout off but it didn’t budge.

Easy fix or no?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Never seen that type of diverter. If I were you I would see if it can be repaired before I would consider replacement. Maybe there is a plastic sealing element that is worn. Is it letting what you think is too much water out the spout when it is set to divert? Or is it failing to stay in the diverted position? Or is it failing to divert at all? If you would disassemble it you might find you could either get a new part or restore the connection the threaded rod makes with the part inside.

Comment: Is water pressure supposed to hold the diverter in the divert position, or do you pull the shorter rod out and rest the end on the outside of the spout?

Comment: Did you look on the bottom for a hole inside which is a set screw?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to replace the spout.

The flats on the top tell me it is threaded on.  Turn it counter-clock-wise.
Since you are replacing it, get a big wrench or large slip joint pliers and grab one of the flats to turn.

Once off, you may need to replace the nipple, or convert to 1/2 inch straight pipe for the new spout.